# I tried to make a POST with react, it works, but my objects are empty when I verify in Postman

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, api, postman

I have this POST to send the score and the name of a player after finnishing the game

```
var sendScoreToAPI = (val) => {
    //get player name from browser prompt
    var playerName = prompt("Good Game, Well Played! Please enter your name: ", "Victor");
    if (playerName != null) {

      var dataToSave = {
        //replace 10 with your actual variable (probably this.state.gameScore or this.state.time)
        playerName: playerName,
        playerScore: val,
        //currentTime: new Date()
      };
      console.log(dataToSave)
      // Actual API call
      fetch(
        "https://localhost:44327/api/MineSweeper", // replace with the url to your API
        {method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
        body: JSON.stringify(dataToSave)}
        )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          (result) => {
            alert('GG '+playerName + "! Ai un scor de "+val);
          },
          // Note: it's important to handle errors here
          (error) => {
            alert('Bad API call');
            console.log(error);
          }
        )
    }
  }
```

It works, in the console I see the right atributtes, but after the POST is empty when I try to GET from Postman.

Comment: Can you confirm that the data is being saved in your back end? If the post works, where is the data stored, do you have a database running or a variable in your server that is storing the data?

Comment: Before I say smth, I am sorry if I don t have the right terminology. I am using ASP .Net core Web Application for this, and there I have the database Context on a class Player

Comment: Can you see the data being stored? When you store the data in your server, Console.WriteLine the data object to confirm it is being persisted. Do the same inside the get endpoint.